# Copy site structure in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've tried to create a Test Environment based on SharePoint developer site.

I have Office 365 subscription, as a result SharePoint Online with already existing site collection. I try to restore structure of this collection in Test Environment.

Is there any way to copy whole structure of this collection(site with subsites)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try to save as template without content, this will save site structure as a template then you can create 2nd site collection using that template.

- Click Save as Template in the top ribbon, type a name, select Include
  Content, and click OK.
- It may take a while to work on it. Go to the Solutions Gallery to
  check it.  Click the gear in the top right->Site Settings->Solutions
  under Web Designer Galleries.
- Download the template to your local.

Then, you can create a new site collection with that template:

- Create a new site collection in SharePoint admin center, and make
  sure select  under Custom tab.
- Access the newly created site collection via the URL. When you access
  it for the first time, you’ll be prompted to select one template.
  Click Solution Gallery.
- Upload the previously downloaded site template file, and click Activate to activate it.
- After the uploaded site template being activated, click BROWSE, and click the icon of site collection to go back to the template pick page.
- Click Custom, click the site template name, then click OK.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/163375.aspx

Comment: Am I right, the procedure 'save as template' save template of one site without subsites? So every subsite should be moved the same way.

Comment: i think if you perform the save as template at site collection level then this will include everything. I am positive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way to do this is with the ShareGate tool (http://en.share-gate.com/). However you can use SharePoint Online PowerShell to do it. Here is a good article to get you started: http://www.itunity.com/article/working-with-spo-site-collection-cmdlets-992.